# iOS CoreBLE only successfully connecting to discovered devices every other discovery

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a device that wakes up occasionally, emits a broadcasts for discovery every 100ms. I am trying to connect to this device **in the background** to read services / characteristics.

The `didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {` method is called every time - the broadcasts are successfully being picked up in the background.

The `didConnectPeripheral...` method, however, is being successfully reached *only* after every other reading. I'm a little stumped as to why:

## Code

```
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
  self.peripheral = peripheral;
  [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {
  [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:self.services options:nil];
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didFailToConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {
    /* NOTE: this is not called ever */
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
  peripheral.delegate = self;
  [peripheral discoverServices:self.services];
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {
  for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
    [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:self.characteristics forService:service];
  }
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {

  for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
    if ([[[characteristic UUID] UUIDString] isEqualToString:@"0321"]) {
      [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];
    }
  }
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {

  const unsigned char *dataBuffer = [[characteristic value] bytes];
  NSUInteger dataLength = [[characteristic value] length];

  /* WHEN THE CODE GETS HERE, IT'S BEEN A SUCCESS! */
}
```

Let me know if there is more relevant information that I can provide!

Comment: When you say "after every other reading" what do you mean? Do you mean that you receive two advertising ("discovery") messages before the connection completes? What's the device's Connection Interval during advertising? Are you using an Apple's recommended intervals? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1931/_index.html

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks for the response. Our BLE device current transmits for 5 seconds (advertising interval is 100ms), is connected to, and then shuts down to conserve power. When it wakes up again and advertises, it is conntected only if it wasn't connected to on the last attempt. It again shuts down after 5 seconds. But data is consistently read successfully on every other attempt.

Comment: If your peripheral is not changing its identifier then you only need to discover it once. Once you know the identifier you can simply issue a `connect` and iOS will complete the connect when the peripheral is seen. Does your app disconnect or does the peripheral close the connection?

Comment: (Totally agree with @Paulw11, you should avoid scanning for a device you already know if you can help it.) "Data is consistently read" and "didConnectPeripheral is called" are different. By "every other attempt" you mean "after 5 seconds, then shutdown, and then the next discovery?" For these kinds of problems, I generally find it's easy to chase the wrong symptom, so nailing down precisely what does and doesn't work is key (and getting rid of every extra variable, like running in the background).

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks for the rules of thumb - seems like good advice. By "every other attempt", I mean the new discovery after the device has woken up again. Wouldn't I have to discover it again if it is just waking up? Maybe there's something I don't quite understand. I do have access to the device, and we're trying to tweak a few parameters on that end.

Comment: @RobNapier the only thing that seems very consistent is that it's working every time in the foreground, but not in the background.

Comment: Once you have an identifier from `didDiscoverPeripheral` you can simply issue a `connect`; if that device isn't currently advertising, iOS will simply hold the connection in a pending state until it is seen and then call your `didConnect` method.  You can use `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers` across app executions to (try) and get a `CBPeripheral` for an identifier you have seen before; this may fail, in which case you need to fall back to scanning. You also need to opt in to state restoration for long-term background reliability

Comment: We have actually discovered the issue. As @RobNapier first suggested, our advertising / connection interval was not according to spec. We decreased from 100ms to 20 ms, and it works perfectly every time now. I'd like to accept that as an answer in case others run into the problem.